# Parameter dependencies based on two datasets in Python toolbox

Tags: arcpy, parameters, python-toolbox

I am setting up the parameters in a Python toolbox. I have a parameter that I would like to list fields based on a user input feature class. I am wondering if it is possible to list fields based on two feature classes.

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    input_data = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "Input data to be fuzzed to a grid",
        name = "input_data",
        datatype = "GPFeatureLayer",
        parameterType = "Required",
        direction = "Input")

    existing_grid = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "Existing Grid",
        name = "site_desc",
        datatype = "GPFeatureLayer",
        parameterType = "Optional",
        direction = "Input")

    output_fields = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName = "Fields to be Included in Output Fuzzed Data",
        name = "output_fields",
        datatype = "Field",
        parameterType = "Required",
        direction = "Input",
        multiValue = True)
    output_fields.parameterDependencies = [input_data.name]
```

I would like for the user to be able to also choose fields from the existing_grid dataset, in addition to the input_data dataset.

How do I include the fields from both in the field list?

I tried adding it separately and including it in the brackets, but this just caused the tool parameter to be blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by [@mikewatt in the comments](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347306/parameter-dependencies-based-on-two-datasets-in-python-toolbox#comment567993_347306), you'll need to custominze this functionality with `arcpy.ListFields`. This will need to be done in the `updateParameters` function. Check for your parameters being altered. If they are, list their fields. Add those fields to your parameter filter.

```
    def getParameterInfo(self):
        input_data = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Input data",
            name = "input",
            datatype = "GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input")

        existing_grid = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Existing Grid",
            name = "site_desc",
            datatype = "GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType = "Optional",
            direction = "Input")

        output_fields = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Fields to be Included",
            name = "output_fields",
            datatype = "GPString",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = True)
        output_fields.filter.list = []

        return [input_data, existing_grid, output_fields]

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        for i in range (2):
            #check if parameter has been changed
            if not parameters [i].hasBeenValidated:
                #empty list to populate with fields
                flds = []
                #iterate both parameters
                for x in range (2):
                    #get parameter
                    fc = parameters [x].valueAsText
                    #check if parameter has been input
                    if fc:
                        #get input feature class fields and add to list
                        flds += [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields (fc)]
                #update field input
                parameters [2].filter.list = flds
```

After one input:

[image: One input feature class]

After two inputs:

[image: Two input feature classes]